# jQueryUI don't load in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

:-)

I have this problem in this morning.

I want to try to use jquery-ui method call .sortable() for a list but I met this problem.
When i load the page in console.log I can see this:
ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Here the code:
this is the

```html
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Sovversivi e Partigiani - Back-end - Gestione Sovversivi</title>
        
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
        <!-- fontawesome -->
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/personale.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
         <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond" rel="stylesheet">
        
    </head>
```

and this is the list(with bootstrap 4)

```html
<div class="row" id="contenutoDaOrdinare">
              <ul class="list-group" id="sortable">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
```

and at the end of body this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
     
</script>   
    <!-- Libreria Jquery Bootstrap -->
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/getusers.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </body>
```

and this is the structure in my root:
[image]

I want to make sortable the list in html.
Can you help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move that inline script after you have loaded the jQuery libraries since it relies on jQuery UI.

```
    <!-- Libreria Jquery Bootstrap -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/getusers.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );

</script>
```

Comment: Very nice!
Thank you very much!